# how to add subject for sendmail

Tags: python, smtp

I am using the following to send an email using smtp..however subject is missing in the email,how to add subject?

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from smtplib import SMTP

def email (body,subject):
    msg = MIMEText("%s" % body)
    msg['Content-Type'] = "text/html; charset=UTF8"
    s = SMTP('localhost',25)
    s.sendmail('userid@company.com', ['userid@company.com'],msg=msg.as_string())

def main ():
    # open gerrit.txt and read the content into body
    with open('gerrit.txt', 'r') as f:
        body = f.read()
    subject = "test email"
    email(body)
    print "Done"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, the subject is just another header.

```
msg['Subject'] = subject
```

Comment: is it like "s.sendmail('userid@company.com', ['userid1@company.com,userid2@company.com'],msg=msg.as_string())"